# Select dropdown item and redirect to different page

Tags: php, codeigniter

**My Code:**

```
select name="accttype">
                <?php foreach($query as $row)
                {
                    $act=$row->accounttype;

                    ?>

                <option value="<?php echo$act;?>"><?php echo$act;?></option>
                  <?php  
                    }
                    ?>



                </select>
```

When I select the dropdown list I want to to redirect different functions to load different pages, like:

```
<option value="<?php echo site_url('Controller_n/function'><?php echo$act;?></option>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use jquery to do this

Comment: can you please send the code

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample:

```
<select id="accttype" name="accttype">
<?php foreach($query as $row)
{
      $act=$row->accounttype;
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $act ?>"><?php echo $act ?></option>
<?php } ?>    
</select>

<script>
    $(function(){
      // bind change event to select
      $('#accttype').on('change', function () {
          var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
          if (url) { // require a URL
              window.location = url; // redirect
          }
          return false;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a id to your select like below

```
<select id="accttype">
<?php foreach($query as $row)
  {  
    $act=$row->accounttype; ?>
   <option value="<?php echo$act;?>"><?php echo$act;?></option>
   <?php } ?>
 </select>
// add jquery library if you not added already
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#accttype').change(function(){
  window.location = $(this).val();
});
});
</script>
```

Hope it will help you.